# Is there anyway to arrange these 2 links so that the link doesn't get written twice?

Tags: javascript, document-body

I got a page I got a link. The link goes to http://stackoverflow.com.

In addition, click anywhere on the link and it goes to http://stackoverflow.com too.

I am just curious. Is there a way to do so without writing stackoverflow.com twice?

Can I make the link in the link to be inactive and clicking the link means the user activate the code written in "onclick" on body?

This is the code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Title</title>
<style>
#centerInScreen {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#centerInScreen h1 {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onclick="window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');">
<div id="centerInScreen">
            <h1 class="auto-style1">
            <a href="http://cjsab.com/?a=540066&amp;c=1200228&amp;m=28&amp;s1=a&amp;s2=b&amp;s3=c&amp;s4=d&amp;s5=e">Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</a></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the code in action here

http://romancepriorities.com/test/index2.html

Basically the link is part of the body. So I want body.onclick to be called when a user click the link.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the HTML *and* JS code you are talking about. The concept of "click[ing] anywhere on the link" is how *all* links work, isn't it?

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 2):

You could give your `a` element an id, and then when the click event happens, you would get the element by that id, and call the `click` method on it:

```
<body>
    <div id="centerInScreen">
    <h1 class="auto-style1">
        <a id="go" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</a>
    </h1>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('go').click();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Note that as you had it, the behaviour was not the same: `location.replace` will not generate an entry in the browser history, so you cannot go back. Also, the `body` element does not necessarily fill the page, so not all clicks would be detected, like is the case with listening to the event on `document`.

#### Two-step link

If you want to have the link "inactive" until it is clicked, and only then allow a navigation to happen on a second click anywhere on the page, then use a variable:

```
<body>
    <div id="centerInScreen">
    <h1 class="auto-style1">
        <a id="go" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</a>
    </h1>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // after doc loaded
    var hasClicked = false;
    var go = document.getElementById('go');
    
    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // only when link was activate with previous click
        if (hasClicked) go.click(); 
    });
    go.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!hasClicked) { // not yet clicked before?
            // log the fact that the link was clicked
            hasClicked = true;
            // but cancel the navigation
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

You would need to use some visual hints so this becomes user-friendly: with classes you could make the link "look" inactive until it receives its first click. Upon that click you could change the style, and maybe its text,...etc. But this goes beyond the question.